# Searching Hash Table Values for Missing Values

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm attempting to search a hash table that contains a hostname as the key and applications as the values. I'm looking for hostnames (keys) that do NOT contain a specific value AKA application. However, my code does not appear to work as I always receive all of the keys/hostnames back.

```
foreach ($global:computer in $global:hash.keys){  
  if ($global:hash.$global:computer.values -notcontains 'SnagIt'){
    $global:computer
}

}
```

**Example Data:**

Key, Values

Host1:FireFox,Chrome,IE

Host2:Snagit,FireFox,Chrome,IE

Host3:Chrome,IE

**Example Value Output from $global:hash.$global:computer:**

{Snagit, FireFox, Chrome, IE...}

**Hash Table Build Code:**

```
$global:Csv = Import-Csv -LiteralPath $global:ConvertedSNWReport

[HashTable]$global:Hash=@{}

For ($i = 0; $i -lt ($global:Csv."Computer name").Count; $i++)
{
If ($global:Hash.ContainsKey($global:Csv[$i].'Computer name'))
{
    $global:Hash.($global:Csv[$i].'Computer name').Application += $global:Csv[$i].Application
    Continue
}
$global:Hash.($global:Csv[$i].'Computer name') = @{
  Application = @($global:Csv[$i].Application)
}
}
```

Comment: Remove `.values`

Comment: That didn't appear to work for me.

Comment: I don't think your hashtable looks like you think it does. The index operator (`[]`) belongs after the list variable, not after the property, e.g. `$global:Csv[$i].'Computer name'`.

Comment: I changed it and it didn't seem to make a difference, as far as I could tell.

Comment: What type do you get from `$Hash.Computer.GetType().FullName`

Comment: When I do "$global:Hash.$global:computer.GetType().FullName" I receive: System.Collections.Hashtable

Comment: Ah, I see.  You need to use `$Hash.Computer.Application` to get the array of programs for that PC.

Comment: That was it, thank you again!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hashtable creation builds the application lists as nested hashtables:

```json
{
    "Host1": {
        "Application": [ "FireFox", "Chrome", "IE" ]
    },
    "Host2": {
        "Application": [ "Snagit", "FireFox", "Chrome", "IE" ]
    },
    "Host3": {
        "Application": [ "Chrome", "IE" ]
    }
}
```

Import your data like this:

```
$hash = @{}
Import-Csv -LiteralPath $global:ConvertedSNWReport | ForEach-Object {
    $hash[$_.'Computer name'] += @($_.Application)
}
```

to get a direct mapping between hostname and list of applications:

```json
{
    "Host1": [ "FireFox", "Chrome", "IE" ],
    "Host2": [ "Snagit", "FireFox", "Chrome", "IE" ],
    "Host3": [ "Chrome", "IE" ]
}
```

With that you can filter the hashtable like this:

```
$hash.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {
    $_.Value -notcontains 'Snagit'
}
```

If you want to stick with your data import procedure (which I do not recommend) you need to expand the `Application` key of the hashtable values:

```
$hash.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {
    $_.Value.Application -notcontains 'Snagit'
}
```

---

As a side note: avoid using global variables whenever you can. They're usually a side channel that introduces unexpected state in your scripts. Particularly do not use global variables as loop variables. In most cases it's better to use local variables and pass data from a caller via script/function parameters.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is an insufficient problem description. Please update your question with how your hashtable is actually defined, like Mathias already requested.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, please see the updated post.

Comment: Thank you very much for this.

Comment: Bonus points if you can show how you can do a -notlike or -notmatch '*Snagit*'

Answer (score 0):

The expression `$hashtable.$key` already resolves to the values of the entry with key `$key`

Remove the `.values` reference from `$global:hash.$global:computer.values`

If the values are just single strings with comma-separated items, `-notcontains` won't work, use the `-notlike` operator instead:

```
if($hash.$computer -notlike '*SnagIt*'){...}
```

Comment: @MrMr Updated the answer. Can you perhaps update your answer with how you constructed the hashtable in the first place?

Comment: the second option you provided didn't work either. I used import-csv to build the hash table.

Comment: @MrMr `Import-Csv` produces a list of objects, not a hashtable. Please update your question with a sample of your actual input data and how you read them. Basically, put a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: I apologize, I used import-csv and then I built a hash table with that data.